# Passing an array of structs to a function. Getting pointer and expression errors

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that displays arrays of structs (like an inventory, with each struct getting its own line). As the title says, I'm having a bit of difficulty trying to write the prototype and header for this function. Here's what I have so far:

```
// Prototype, before main (where "Product" and "inventory[50]" are declared and initialized)
void displayTable(struct Product inventory[]);

// Calling displayTable in main()
displayTable(inventory[]);


// The function itself
void displayTable(Product* inventory[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        cout << inventory[i].name << " " << inventory[i].inStock << " " << inventory[i].unitPrice << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a whole bunch of errors with this. First is under the last bracket when I call the function, I get "expected an expression". And I get "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" under each "inventory" in the for loop inside the function.

Comment: Is `displayTable(inventory[])` actually within your `int main()`'s curly braces?

Comment: You have two functions named `displayTable`. You have declared a function `void displayTable(struct Product inventory[])` that takes an array of `struct Product`s. You have defined a *completely different* function `void displayTable(Product* inventory[])` that takes an array of `Product*`. A `struct Product` is NOT a `Product*`.

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 Yes it is. It's right before "return 0;", after everything else

Comment: @John Ah, I missed that, thank you. That doesn't seem to have fixed the errors, however.

Comment: What change did you make?

Comment: Why would you prototype a function one way and then define it a different way? The prototype is supposed to describe the fuction, not be different to it.

Comment: And `displayTable(inventory[]);` should be `displayTable(inventory);`. Use `[]` for array indexing and array declarations, neither apply here.

Comment: Many errors in this code snippet and it is incomplete, making it hard to fully diagnose and answer. I recommend producing  a [mcve] that focuses on one error. While they make questions clearer, the true beauty of the MRE is making one often reduces the noise around the bug to the point that you can find and solve the bug without further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is not C. You don't need to keep putting the word `struct` before things that are `struct`.

You have two functions named `displayTable`. You have declared a function `void displayTable(struct Product inventory[])` that takes an array of `struct Product`s. You have defined a *completely different* function `void displayTable(Product* inventory[])` that takes an array of `Product*`. A `struct Product` is NOT a `Product*`.

The solution is to change your function signature to `void displayTable(Product inventory[])`, and use this exact signature for both the forward-declaration and the definition.

Comment: I changed that and now "Product" in the prototype is giving an error: "identifier is undefined". I'm assuming that's because "Product" is declared as a struct in the function main()? If so, I don't know how to fix that as our professor is banning us from using global objects and variables.

Comment: Generally you declare your `struct`s in the global scope. Outside of `main`. If you just have one `.cpp` file, you put all your `struct`s and `class`es after all of your `#include`s

Comment: A `struct` declared at the global namespace is NOT a global object. Just don't create an instance of `Product` in the global scope and you'll be fine.